# why 10-fold cross validation is even faster than 1-fold fit when using LGB?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, model-fitting, lightgbm

I am using LGB to handle a machine leaning task. But I found when I use the sklearn API `cross_val_score` and set `cv=10`, the time cost is less than single fold fit. I splited dataset useing `train_test_split`, then fit a LGBClassifier on training set. The time cost of latter is much more than former, why?

Sorry for my bad English.

Environment: Python 3.5, scikit-learn 0.20.3, lightgbm 2.2.3
Inter Xeon CPU E5-2650 v4
Memory 128GB

```py
X = train_df.drop(['uId', 'age'], axis=1)
Y = train_df.loc[:, 'age']
X_test = test_df.drop(['uId'], axis=1)

X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.1,
                                                  stratify=Y)

# (1809000, 12) (1809000,) (201000, 12) (201000,) (502500, 12)
print(X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_val.shape, Y_val.shape, X_test.shape)

from lightgbm import LGBMClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import time

lgb = LGBMClassifier(n_jobs=-1)

tic = time.time()
scores = cross_val_score(lgb, X, Y,
                         scoring='accuracy', cv=10, n_jobs=-1)
toc = time.time()
# 0.3738402985074627 0.0009231167322574765 300.1487271785736
print(np.mean(scores), np.std(scores), toc-tic)

tic = time.time()
lgb.fit(X_train, Y_train)
toc = time.time()
# 0.3751492537313433 472.1763586997986 (is much more than 300)
print(accuracy_score(Y_val, lgb.predict(X_val)), toc-tic)
```

Comment: You're using `n_jobs=-1` for both the classifier and `cross_val_score` which will use all your cores regardless of whether you are cross validating or not.

Comment: Run the exact same code but this time set `n_jobs = None` and see the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the answer. Here writtens in documentation of LightGBM: 'for the best speed, set this to the number of real CPU cores, not the number of threads'. So set `n_jobs=-1` is not a best choice.